# Angular2 RC5 ahead-of-time compiler not generating factory .js files?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the offline compiler to compile my app ahead-of-time using Angular2 RC5.

I can compile my code to a 'dist' directory successfully. To do this I am compiling with main.ts like this:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Then modifying dist/main.js to this:

```
var platform_browser_1 = require('@angular/platform-browser');
var app_module_ngfactory_1 = require('./app/app.module.ngfactory');
platform_browser_1.platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(app_module_ngfactory_1.AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Otherwise I was getting an error saying that app.module.ngfactory wasn't found as it hadn't been generated yet.

Compiling also produces an 'app' sub-directory of 'dist' containing all of the ngfactory files for my components and the app module. However, only .ts files are produced. So when I attempt to run the app in a browser, I get an error like this:

> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   https://mysiteaddress.com/dist/app/app.module.ngfactory.js

So this is where I'm confused. How to generate app.module.ngfactory.js?

I also tried modifying main.ts in various ways based on [this](http://angularjs.blogspot.ie/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html) post, but then I found I couldn't re-compile as my app.module.ngfactory file was in a directory that wasn't part of the app's root directory. Tsc was also producing errors along the lines of

> app/chat-operations.component.ngfactory.ts(377,27): error TS2341:
>   Property 'volume_title' is private and only accessible within class
>   'ChatOperationsComponent'.

Could someone explain where I'm going wrong with this? Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working in the end (reducing load time by over 6 seconds) by removing all of the uses 'private' when declaring variables before the constructor in components. This was causing many errors as mentioned above. Declaring variables private seemed to be acceptable in Services and Directives. That was the only major obstacle. Still don't know why...

Comment: Are you referencing private variables from the component template?

Comment: Yes, often I was using private variables for *ngIf expressions, as inputs to child components, etc. This worked fine when compiling just-in-time. I don't know why it should be different for the ahead-of-time compiler.

Comment: Unlike JIT, the offline compiler uses the TypeScript compiler and so enforces more stringent checks like member visibility.